# data normalization in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

I read multiple posts about normalizing data in case of neural networks. One question - does normalization also help in reducing values of the input to sigmoid function - `z=x1*w1+x2*w3....` ?

Andrew Ng recommends ([video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/lXv6U/normalizing-inputs)) setting variance of Weights in a layer to be equal to 1. He mentions that this allows z to also take on values on a similar scale - mean 0 and variance 1.

on a similar note, wont normalization of inputs help to bring value of z down? if my X1 has range in billions then my weight need to be very small. and it will cause gradient descent to take a lot of iterations.

my main question -
**lets say data has multiple inputs and all of them have 1 variance and similar means, but Xs are in millions. IN such case wont normalization help?**

Comment: Can you give a link to where Andrew Ng is stating his recommendation?

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/lXv6U/normalizing-inputs - i have also updated my question

Comment: There's nothing in the mathematics of canonical neural networks which requires feature normalisation. Normalisation has become common practice in _some_ applications where a performance boost has been observed but this cannot be considered as "standard practice", in my opinion.